# Python: PEP 8 class name as variable

Tags: python, pep8

Which is the convention according to PEP 8 for writing variables that identify class names (not instances)?

That is, given two classes, `A` and `B`, which of the following statements would be the right one?

```
target_class = A if some_condition else B
instance = target_class()
```

or

```
TargetClass = A if some_condition else B
instance = TargetClass()
```

---

As stated in the style guide,

> **Class Names**:
>
> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

But also

> **Method Names and Instance Variables:**
>
> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

In my opinion, these two conventions clash and I can't find which one prevails.

Comment: Classes use CamelCase.  Variable names (instances) use_underscore_lower_case

Comment: Why didn't you [just look it up](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did, but I still find it unclear. Class names should normally use the CapWords convention, ok, but variables don't. These two conventions clash, in my opinion, so I don't know which one prevails.

Comment: I would lean more towards `variable_style`. I can't see anything immediately in PEP8 that answers this, but thinking of it as a variable makes more sense to me. Using `ClassStyle` makes it look like it is the natural name of a class that is defined somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Interesting - I would lean towards `ClassStyle`. `TargetClass`, although it could be `A` or `B`, is still a class and when it is "called" it still constructs an instance.

Comment: I don't think PEP8 specifically mentions this, but I don't think it needs to, it's a variable, it references a type but it's still a variable so I'd use the variable style.

Comment: since you're using it internally, it really doesn't matter. Pick either one.

Comment: `TargetClass` or `target_factory`.

Comment: From your question its clear you are trying to find the difference between `Variable` and `Class Name` but since both `TargetClass` or `target_factory` are just a variable to hold class object (either A or B). So I think as per PEP8 we should go with `target_factory`

Comment: Not an answer to the general question, but alternatively, you could also write `instance = (A if somecondition else B)()` and circumvent the problem.

Comment: @MaNKuR `A` and `B` are also variables to hold the classes. That they have the same name as the variables holding them is just a result of how they are created.

Comment: `A`, `B` and `TargetClass` are all names that reference a class. The assignment  `buffalo_ny = TargetClass()` clearly conveys the meaning that `buffalo_ny` references an instance of a class.

Comment: Agree @glglgl, but since `A` and `B` are class variable referencing to itself (that means class is declared with the same name). So as per `class naming convention` its fine but the moment I create new different reference of that class then in this case we have to follow the `variable naming convention`.

Comment: It seems according to the comments that it's stated nowhere how exactly it shall be done, so everyone has a different interpretation. Shouldn't PEP 8 explicitly cover this case?

Comment: PEP8 proposes also to name your variables according to their usage. In this case, I would say that the variable style should apply, but including the suffix `_class` in the variable name like you did for instance to precise that this variable points to a class.

Comment: @Frodon That sounds like a good option.

Comment: Please use `TargetClass`.  *Every* class is a variable.  The point is to show intent so that someone reading your code doesn't have to scan back to the variable definition to determine whether they're working with an instance or a class.

Answer (score 15):

In lack of a specific covering of this case in PEP 8, one can make up an argument for both sides of the medal:

One side is: As `A` and `B` both are variables as well, but hold a reference to a class, use CamelCase (`TargetClass`) in this case.

Nothing prevents you from doing

```
class A: pass
class B: pass
x = A
A = B
B = x
```

Now `A` and `B` point to the respectively other class, so they aren't really fixed to the class.

So `A` and `B` have the only responsibility to hold a class (no matter if they have the same name or a different one), and so has `TargetClass`.

---

In order to remain unbiased, we as well can argue in the other way: `A` and `B` are special in so far as they are created along with their classes, and the classes' internals have the same name. In so far they are kind of "original", any other assignment should be marked special in so far as they are to be seen as a variable and thus in `lower_case`.

---

The truth lies, as so often, somewhere in the middle. There are cases where I would go one way, and others where I would go the other way.

Example 1: You pass a class, which maybe should be instantiated, to a method or function:

```
def create_new_one(cls):
    return cls()

class A: pass
class B: pass

print(create_new_one(A))
```

In this case, `cls` is clearly of very temporary state and clearly a variable; can be different at every call. So it should be `lower_case`.

Example 2: Aliasing of a class

```
class OldAPI: pass
class NewAPI: pass
class ThirdAPI: pass
CurrentAPI = ThirdAPI
```

In this case, `CurrentAPI` is to be seen as a kind of alias for the other one and remains constant throughout the program run. Here I would prefer `CamelCase`.

Comment: I see that the decision is made by your opinion (which IMO makes sense), but it's not completely convincing. The opposite option is also well defended at the comments.

Comment: @LostMyGlasses I now show both sides unbiased and show when I would use the one and when the other.

Comment: I think that both cases are well explained, and as seen that it is a matter of personal decision, your tips are helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In case of doubt I would do the same as Python developers. They wrote the PEP-8 after all.

You can consider your line:

```
target_class = A if some_condition else B
```

as an in-line form of the pattern:

```
target_class = target_class_factory()
```

and there is a well-known example for it in the Python library, the [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), which uses CamelCase.

Comment: Wow, that's a good example. However, I'd like to know not only _how_ to do it, but also _why_.

Comment: @LostMyGlasses The "why" of any code style recommendation is almost always the same. 1) consistency and 2) maintainability.  The CapWords/CamelCase style is more maintainable because someone hacking on the code doesn't have to dredge up the variable definition to know what they're working with.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think that whether the variable you mentioned, which holds a reference to a class, is defined as a temporary variable (for example in a procedure or function) or as a derivation from an existing class in the global spectrum has the most weight in the case of which one to use. So to summarise from the reply above:

- If the variable is temporary, e.g. inside a function or used in a single instance in the solving of a problem, it should be `lower_case` with underscore separation.
- If the variable is within the global spectrum, and is defined along with the other classes as an alias or derivation to use to create objects in the body of the program, it should be defined using `CamelCase`.

Comment: Why is it less important to have this information in a function than at the top level?  I guess because functions are smaller?  What about function arguments?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found some light in the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names):

> **Class Names**
>
> [...]
>
> The naming convention for functions may be used instead in cases where the interface is documented and used primarily as a callable.

*may be used* is not a strong statement, but it covers the case, as the variable was intended to be used as a callable.

So, for general purpose I think that

```
target_class = A if some_condition else B
instance = target_class()
```

is better than

```
TargetClass = A if some_condition else B
instance = TargetClass()
```

Comment: That's not using it as a callable.  That's using it as a class.